# What should be a naming convention for Ajax classes: Button or ButtonView?

Tags: javascript, ajax, class, oop, naming-conventions

We are creating Ajax library which contains visual controls, such as Buttons, Toolbars, Separators. What would be the best way to name classes that represent visual objects in our library? What is the typical naming conventions in Ajax?

Should we call our classes

```
ButtonView
ToolbarView
SeparatorView
```

or

```
Button
Toolbar
Separator
```

?

Comment: This question is more about if it is typical to add 'View' or any other prefixes or suffixes to classes that represent visual elements comparing to non-visual elements. All classes are located inside namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think a prefix add your object is a good idea.like jq-button or paper-button,prefix can be your project name,but not too long.a good name can help people to difference your project and most important, it make people to REMEMBER your project

Comment: All classes are inside namespaces, such as MyNs.MyClass. So the question is only about the class names.

Answer (score 0):

Since JavaScript doesn't have *classes*, but rather constructors (and plain functions) -- I'd say that the answer to that question really has more to do with your namespacing:

```
myWidgetFactor.createButton(...)
```

This ties in with the DOM naming convention:

```
document.createElement("input");
document.createTextNode("...");
document.createDocumentFragment();
```

(Just as a side note, from your question, I can't figure out what any of this question has to do with Ajax...)